# Is there anyway to trigger the google Fastclick event

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have bound a fastClick event to a button

```
$('#back').fastClick(function(e) {

});
```

Which gets called fine, but inside that, depending on the data attribute that is set on the #back button i want to trigger another fastclick on another element. So example code may look like this.

```
$('#back').fastClick(function(e) {
    var     history = window.localStorage.getItem("history").split(","),
            lastPage = history[history.length - 2];

    if (lastPage == 'null') {
        return false;
    } else {
        switch (lastPage) {
            case "userSummaryWrapper":
            case "ladder":
                $('li.summary').trigger('fastClick');
            break;
            case "currentBattles":
                $('li.battles').trigger('fastClick');
            break;
            case "workouts":
            case "workoutDetailWrapper":
                $('li.workouts').trigger('fastClick');
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

The triggers don't get fired as expected. If i trigger a normal click, it works on normal browsers but not on mobile browsers which is what i'm targeting.. Has anyone had any experience like that?

Comment: Try `.fastClick()` instead of `.trigger('fastClick')`. Or, based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1683277), simply `.click()`.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for getting back to me quickly.. I tried both and unfortunately neither worked. Triggering a .click() works on a normal web browser but not on mobile which is what i'm developing for... Any other ideas?